# Combinations of a matrix (rows and columns)

Tags: java, eclipse, matrix, multidimensional-array

Good afternoon, I'm having problems finding all the combinations of a matrix.

I am testing with a 4x4 matrix but I can not get the approximate 2000 possible combinations of its elements, but I only generate 256 combinations. The idea is to take into account the repetitions to reach this number.

The problem is that my algorithm does not create the combinations of the rows. Explained graphically with a 2x2 matrix:

[Correct solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8oIo.png)

The correct solution would be the image above, but it only generates 4 combinations.

[Solution thrown by the algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox8Nr.png)

My code is:

```
package ia;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Nodo implements Iterator<String> {

Nodo anterior = null;
Nodo raiz = null;

int posicion = 0;   
List<String> columnas = new LinkedList<>(); 
int indicesTotales = 0;

public Nodo(List<String> columnas, Nodo anterior, Nodo raiz) {

    this.columnas = columnas;

    this.anterior = anterior;
    this.raiz = raiz;

    this.posicion = 0;
    this.indicesTotales = columnas.size() - 1;      
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {

    try {       
        if (this.raiz != null && this.raiz.posicion <= this.raiz.indicesTotales) {              
            return true;            
        } else if (this.posicion > this.indicesTotales) {               
            return false;           
        } else {            
            return false;           
        }       
    } catch (Exception exception) { 
        System.out.println(exception);      
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Aún no es compatible.");   
}

@Override
public String next() {

    if (this.posicion >= this.indicesTotales) {

        if (this.anterior != null) {            
            this.posicion = 0;
            this.anterior.next();
        } else {
            ++this.posicion;            
        }       
    } else {        
        ++this.posicion;        
    }       
    return null;
}

public String actual() {
    return columnas.get(this.posicion); 
}

@Override
public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
}
```

2.

```
package ia;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Combinaciones {

private Nodo iterador = null;

public Combinaciones(String[][] lista) {

    Nodo raiz = null;
    Nodo aux = null;

    for (String[] columnas : lista) {

        aux = new Nodo(new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(columnas)), aux, raiz);

        if (raiz == null) {
            raiz = aux;
        }
    }
    iterador = aux;
}

public int generar() {

    int contador = 0;

    while (iterador.hasNext()) {
        Nodo aux = iterador;
        System.out.print(aux.actual());
        while (aux.anterior != null) {
            System.out.print(" " + aux.anterior.actual());
            aux = aux.anterior;
        }
        iterador.next();
        System.out.println();
        contador++;
    }
    return contador;
}
}
```

3.

```
package ia;

public class Prueba {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Combinaciones lista = new Combinaciones(
            new String[][] { { "1", "2" }, { "3", "4" } } );
    System.out.println("\n" + lista.generar());
}
}
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me solve the error.
Tranks.

Comment: According to your sample, there is no meaning in rows and columns, they just contain the data (a,b,c,d) where you combine each element with each other, except for (aa,bb,cc,dd) but ab and ba are both generated?

Comment: How do you want to get from 4x4 values to 2000 combinations? Each of the 16 elements combined with 15 other elements, That leads to 240 pairs - counting elements in the pairs it's 480.

Comment: *approximate 2000 possible combinations*? There are exactly  43680 combinations of elements in 4x4 matrix... Formula is **16!/(16-4)!** = **16*15*14*13** = 43680